# How can I get my sidebar to have a grey background colour?

Tags: php, html, css

I have 2 css files and a html file. There is a sidebar to the left of the page and it has the same background colour as the rest of the page. What I want is for the sidebar to have a different background colour to the rest of the page (dark grey), but this isn't working out, probably because of the clash between both css files, but can someone please help me?

changePassAdmin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "sidebar.css">
<title>Change Password</title>
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 50%; } th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; } tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
tr:hover {background-color: #e2f4ff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul>

<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>View Personal Information</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>View Expense Claims</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>View Payslips</a></li>
<li><a  class=active >Change Password</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Maintain Employee Information</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Maintain Tax Information</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Maintain Payroll Items</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Maintain Timesheet</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Maintain Employee Expenses</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Run Payroll</a></li>
<li><a  href=PersonalInfoOutput>Generate Reports</a></li>

</ul>

<div style=margin-left:25%;padding:1px;>
</div>

    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <form action ="NewPassword" method = post> 

    <table border ="1"> 

    <tr>
    <td>Existing Password:</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "oldpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>New Password:</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "newpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Confirm New Password</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "confirmpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Update Password">
    </form>.
</body>

</html>
```

main.css

```
body {
    text-align: center; 
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        background-color:  #f0f0f4 ;

    }

table { 
    margin: auto; 
    }

input[type=submit] {

  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #018dc4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal 16px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #0099ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(15,73,168,0.66) ;

    }


input[type=text] { 
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal 18px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #e2f4ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.66) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

input[type=password] { 
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: normal 18px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #e2f4ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.66) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

h1 { 

    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 76, 255, 0.2);
    color: #0099FF;
    font-size: 43px;
}
```

sidebar.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: isn't it already a different color? https://jsfiddle.net/rkvvrm7e/

Comment: Isn't the sidebar showing a green color: background-color: #4CAF50;

Comment: @ThomasByy That's only li. a.active - so only when class=active that will turn green. As you can see in the html file.

Comment: It is also on the ul element. You can change the side bar color by changing the ul { background-color: #4CAF50; } element.

Comment: @ThomasByy Ah, thanks very much man! That really helped me, appreciate it. By the way, any idea how I can move the change password table a bit more to the right? If you run it on jsfiddle.net/rkvvrm7e you can see that the table is touching the sidebar, and I want it to move a bit further away to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the side bar color by changing the ul { background-color: #4CAF50; } element.

To get some padding between the login box and sidebar you can wrap your login box code in a div and add a margin.

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <form action ="NewPassword" method = post> 
        <!--FORM DETAILS-->
    </form>
</div>

#container {
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

As a general rule you want to include all your content in at least one div. That gives you the ability to do things like adding margin and padding.

Before you go too much further I recommend looking at basic HTML coding. Things like tables and inline styles are not considered good coding practices these days.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Will be a good start.